# A natural way of inquiring the length of time elapsed since a certain act in the past

Tags: phrase-request

"***How long have you opened it?***", as far as I understand, means pretty much the same as "***How long have you been opening it?***", that is, "***How much time have you already spent trying to open it?***" or, in case of repetitive acts of opening, "***How much time have you already spent performing repetitive acts of opening it?***"

However, what if I want to know about the length of time that has transpired since the time (one single time) of opening something?

The best option that I have on my mind is simply "***When did you open it?***". However, it's more a question about a point in time rather than a queston about the length of time. The answer could be then something like "***On March 3rd, 2019***". But what I would need instead would be the length of time from March 3rd, 2019, until now.

So, what would be the most natural way in English to ask what I want to ask here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few examples:

> How much time has it been since you opened it?
> How much time has passed since you opened it?
> How long has it been since you opened it?

This might be less formal, but you can also say:

> How long since you opened it?

One of the comments indicates that in British English, you might also say:

> How long have you opened it?

Comment: Very good examles. Thank you!!!

Comment: I would understand 'How long have you opened it?' to mean the same as 'How long is it since you opened it?' in casual UK conversation.

Comment: That must be a British thing because you won't hear that in American English. I modified the answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would go in a slightly different direction, without focusing on who performed the opening:

> How long has it been open?

If you don't mind a bit of squabble from some old-school purists who will claim that you shouldn't end sentences with a preposition, you could even go for

> How long has it been open for?

Comment: Good suggestions. Thank you! May I ask, is it more American or more British English?